# Standard Normal Distribution and Probability Limit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let ${Y}_i$  be i.i.d random variables with i= 1,...,n each normally distributed at N(10,4).

a. Solve for P(9.6 ≤ $\bar{Y}$ ≤ 10.4) when the sample size equals i.) n=20 ii.) n=100 iii.) n=1000

b.Let c be a positive number. Show that P( 10-c ≤ $\bar{Y}$ ≤ 10+c) approaches 1 as n grows large.

c. Use (b) to show that the probability limit of $\bar{Y}$ is 10.

I already answered a.i. and a.ii. How should I go about the remaining items? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Laws of Large Numbers.

Comment: @SeanRoberson okay, but do you think I can use the theorem for the consistency of an estimate for b, and for c can i use the theorem for asymptotically unbiased estimators?